# Delphi Non Blocking ShowModal

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, tform

I was wondering if theres a method to show a TForm without waiting for it (kinda like TForm.Show). But what I would like is to BLOCK all other forms (just like in ShowModal)

Example:

I have Form1 and Form2. 
Form1 has a button that should open Form2 but Form1 is blocked, yet the click of the button still continues the code that came AFTER Form2 opened.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal; // ===> Something like that but the Code should continue, yet Form1 and all other forms are blocked (disabled)
  MessageBox (0, 'Code continues', '', 0);
end;
```

Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Can you write your code in `Application.OnModalBegin`?

Comment: You attach a method to the property, probably in `OnCreate` of your main form. `Application.OnModalBegin:=AppModalBegin` where `procedure AppModalBegin(Sender:TObject)` is in your form's class declaration maybe in private section f.i.. In the method you call MessageBox: `TForm1.AppModalBegin begin MessageBox(..`

Comment: I just tried that but how would that continue the code from TForm1.Button1Click?

Comment: It won't. You won't be able to do that. That was just one alternative place to call MessageBox.

Comment: So I guess I have to disable all the forms manually to make it work like that...

Comment: Probably. You can duplicate part of the code in `TCustomForm.ShowModal`.

Comment: Can't you just hide the `Form1`?

Comment: I don't wanna hide it, I just want to to "block/disable" it. But I have a lot of forms, so I would need to disable every form...

Comment: What is the benefit of having a non modal window being the only one which is not disabled? From the user's point of view there is no difference between your approach and a simple call to `ShowModal`. Just move the code which is to be executed into Form2. Usually, it belongs there anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call DisableTaskwindows, excepting your Window from beeing disabled and later EnableTaskWindows to enable other forms again.

```
  Form3.Show;
  FP:=DisableTaskwindows(Form3.Handle);
  //Some Code
  EnableTaskwindows(FP);
```

Comment: that doesnt make the new Form Modal though

Comment: It doesn't matter! This is exactly what I was looking for and it works! Thank you very much. If you wanna know why I need this is because I can open a "progress Window" while actual code is being processed

Comment: @Benjamin This is the wrong solution to that problem. You can easily solve the problem with a modal form. This answers the question that you asked though.

Comment: If there's a possibility to have StayOnTop forms, I suggest also to have a look at `Normalize[All]TopMosts` `RestoreTopMosts` of Application.

Comment: Sorry to get back to this question but do I need to call `DisableTaskwindows` and `EnableTaskwindows` in the Mainthread?